# django many to many field annotate and count

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

```
I have a model :
class Question(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.TextField()
    answers = models.ManyToManyField('Answer',related_name='answer_name', blank=True)
```

Here what  I want is I want to list all the question which dont have any answer.

I did:

```
un_list = Question.objects.annotate(a_count="Answers").filter(a_count=0)
```

Is it right way of doing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close. Here's what you probably want:

```
from django.db.models import Count
un_list = Question.objects.annotate(a_count=Count("answer")).filter(a_count=0)
```